# How to properly order outcomes in tidycmprsk subdistribution hazard (crr)?

Tags: r, model, hazard, competing-risks

This feels like a naive question, but I am a bit confused by the documentation and vignettes that I have found for tidycmprsk and the instructions I have been given for my exercise.

I am trying to estimate the relationship between a predictor protein X and future dementia risk while accounting for mortality as a competing risk with the development of dementia. The instructions that I have been given by a colleague are to code non-events as 0, mortality events as 1, and dementia events as 2. I was told that this should give me the hazard ratio for the protein X and dementia while accounting for competing risks if I use the following syntax:

`model <- crr(Surv(time_to_event, event) ~ covariates + protein_X, data=data)`

However, the documentation for [tidycmprsk crr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidycmprsk/tidycmprsk.pdf) states that when failcode is unspecified, the first competing event will be used as the event of interest. Wouldn't the first competing event following the coding I was provided be death, since it is coded as 1? Further, [this vignette](https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html#Part_3:_Competing_Risks) shows cause-specific mortality coded as 1 and other mortality coded as 2.

Can someone help me understand what the appropriate coding should be to get the hazard ratio of protein X and dementia? I have tried recoding in the opposite direction (i.e. dementia as 1 and death as 2) and the results look fairly similar to the results obtained when using the coding provided to me - am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about this type of model? Any help would be appreciated!